# I need a new shingle roof, does the 12/2 minimum pitch still apply if I use peel-n-stick?

Tags: roof, waterproofing

Does the 12/2 minimum pitch rule for shingles still apply if peel-n-stick is first applied to the roof deck? Why would I have to put down a membrane on 12/1 pitch above the porch, instead of shingles, if there is peel-n-stick? And then can't I just install the shingles right over the peel-n-stick? I just want the whole roof to look the same. I live in FL.

Comment: As an aside, the typical expression of slope is rise-over-run: 2/12 or 2 in 12

Answer (score 3):

If there are not asphalt shingles and  it meets the manufacturer specs for install, I can't find why not but you may still need to get it approved.

All from Florida Building Code 2004

> ## CHAPTER 9: ROOF ASSEMBLIES
>
> ### **SECTION R905 REQUIREMENTS FOR ROOF COVERINGS**
>
> **R905.1 Roof covering applications.** Roof coverings shall be applied in accordance with  the applicable provisions of this section and the
>   manufacturer’s installation instructions.
>
> **R905.2 Asphalt shingles.** The installation of asphalt shingles shall comply with the  provisions of this section.
>
> **R905.2.1** Sheathing requirements. Asphalt shingles shall be fastened to solidly sheathed decks.
>
> **R905.2.2** Slope. Asphalt shingles shall only be used on roof slopes of two units vertical in 12 units horizontal (2:12) or greater. For
>   roof slopes from two units vertical in 12 units horizontal (2:12) up
>   to four units vertical in 12 units horizontal (4:12), double
>   underlayment application is required in accordance with Section
>   R905.2.7.
>
> **R905.2.3** Underlayment.  Unless otherwise noted, required underlayment shall conform to ASTM D 226 Type I, ASTM D 4869 Type I,
>   or ASTM D 6757. Self-adhering polymer modified bitumen sheet shall
>   comply with ASTM D 1970.
>
> **R905.2.7** Underlayment application.  For roof slopes from two
>   units vertical in 12 units horizontal (17-percent slope), up to four
>   units vertical in 12 units horizontal (33-percent slope), underlayment
>   shall be two layers applied in the following manner. Apply a 19-inch
>   (483 mm) strip of underlayment felt parallel to and starting at the
>   eaves, fastened sufficiently to hold in place. Starting at the eave,
>   apply 36-inch-wide (914 mm) sheets of underlayment, overlapping
>   successive sheets 19 inches (483 mm), and fastened sufficiently to
>   hold in place. Distortions in the underlayment shall not interfere
>   with the ability of the shingles to seal. For roof slopes of four
>   units vertical in 12 units horizontal (33-percent slope) or greater,
>   underlayment shall be one layer applied in the following manner.
>   Underlayment shall be applied shingle fashion, parallel to and
>   starting from the eave and lapped 2 inches (51 mm), fastened
>   sufficiently to hold in place. Distortions in the underlayment shall
>   not interfere with the ability of the shingles to seal. End laps shall
>   be offset by 6 feet (1829 mm).
>
> ## CHAPTER 1 ADMINISTRATION
>
> ### SECTION 104 DUTIES AND POWERS OF BUILDING OFFICIAL
>
> **104.11 Alternative materials, design and methods of construction and equipment.**  The provisions of this code are not intended to prevent
>   the installation of any material or  to prohibit any design or method
>   of construction not specifically prescribed by this code,  provided
>   that any such alternative has been approved. An alternative material,
>   design or  method of construction shall be approved where the building
>   official finds that the  proposed design is satisfactory and complies
>   with the intent of the provisions of this  code, and that the
>   material, method or work offered is, for the purpose intended, at
>   least  the equivalent of that prescribed in this code in quality,
>   strength, effectiveness, fire  resistance, durability and safety. When
>   alternate life safety systems are designed, the 
>   *SFPE Engineering Guide to Performance-Based Fire Protection Analysis and Design of  Buildings*, or other methods approved by the building
>   official may be used. The building  official shall require that
>   sufficient evidence or proof be submitted to substantiate any  claim
>   made regarding the alternative.

**Note: Also be aware of local amendments and declaratory statements**

Comment: @richardraustad the 2/12 slope merits *Double* underlayment.  As Jason mentions, you will need the manufactures specs showing asphalt shingles over 1/12 are even allowed, to start.

Comment: @HerrBag, yes double underlayment if felt, but I hope I would not have to double the peel-n-stick, it seems pointless and would be costly. I'll call the code enforcement office. Thanks.

Comment: These codes are rock bottom minimums to assure safety; they're not trying to legislate excellence here. So it's a cautionary tale: shingle roofs struggle to function properly on a 4:12 roof angle or less.  I would go with a different roofing system.  Metal roofs work fine at much shallower angles, and rubber roofs work literally flat.